# Java- Count from 1 - 5000 and put it in 5 columns

Tags: java

Can't figure it out. Need to use a for/while statement. First month learning Java so please keep it simple. Thanks

This is what I have so far:

```
public class prog6c
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int x = 1;
    while (x<5000){
        for (x=1; x<5; ++x)
            System.out.print(" "+x);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly a question about coding problems, more a request for homework help or instruction, which SO doesn't provide. You're pretty far from solution. I suggest  you give it more thought. Also, the question title is pretty vague about how to put the numbers into 5 columns. Maybe if you give that some more thought, the solution might become clear to you.

Comment: you've created a infinite loop by resetting `x=1;` in for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that after going through the for loop for the first time `x<=5`. But the next time you are setting it back to 1.

I would suggest a loop until `5000` which prints a line break when x can be divide by `5`

```
for (x = 1; x < 5000; ++x)
{
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(x);
    if (x % 5 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhhh. The modulous operator. Never thought of that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the purpose of what you are trying to achieve, check out the following code sample. I haven't tested it out. But it should work on most part:

```
public class Prog6c {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        while (x<5000){
           for (y=1; y<=5; ++y)
              System.out.print(x++ + " ");
           System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing:

```
int x = 1;
int columns = 1;

while(x < 5000){
    for(x = 1; x < 5; x++){
        while(columns < 5){
            if(columns ==){
                columns == 0
                System.out.print("\n")
            }
            columns++;
            System.out.print("      " + x);
        }
    }
}
```

This code count by 0 to 5000 aligning in 5 columns per row.

Frank.